# Angular ng route

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to setup these routes below, but when I test they are not working, can someone please assist me with this. When I click on any of the  links below, they do not work

```
'use strict'
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", 'firebase']);

  myApp.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'myfirebase Url' );

myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$routeProvider
   .when('/',
         {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',
          controller: 'mainController'
         })
    .when('/login', {
         templateUrl:'partials/login.html',
         controller: 'loginSignupController'

         })
     .when('/signup', {
          templateUrl:'partials/signup.html',
          controller:'loginSignupController' 
        } )
    .when('/dash', {
          templateUrl:'partials/dashboard.html',
          controller:'mainController' 
        } ).

     otherwise({
         redirectTo:'/'
     });

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Signup.html

```
<h1>Welcome to Signup</h1>

<a class="" ng-href="/">Go Home</a>
<form class="ui form">
<div class="field">
<label>Username </label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="username" placeholder="password">
</div>


 <button class="ui button" type="submit" ng-submit="">Signup</button>
</form>
```

login.html
   This is the login page 
    Go Home
    
    
    Username 
    
    
    
    Password

```
</div>
<button class="ui button" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

home.html

```
  <div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui large secondary inverted pointing menu">
    <a class="toc item">
      <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="active item">Home</a>
    <a class="item">About Us</a>
    <a class="item">Send</a>
    <a class="item">Request</a>  
    <a class="item">How it Works</a>
    <div class="right item">
      <a class="ui inverted button" ng-href="partials/login">Log in</a>
      <a class="ui inverted button" ng-href="partials/signup">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you refered to angular and angular route in html?

Comment: you have `ng-view` on `index.html`?

Comment: why do trying to redirect to `ng-href="partials/login"`? The route path is **/login** so change it to `ng-href="/login"` (Do the same for the other links)

Comment: the `ng-href`s are supposed to point to the name of the route you made. So it should be `ng-href="login"` and `ng-href="signup"`

Comment: lol @AlonEitan great minds think alike

Comment: thanks everyone, I will try again and see, i will let you know of  the result

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var App = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.router"]);
MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Redirect any unmatched url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");  

$stateProvider

    // Dashboard
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",            
        data: {pageTitle: 'Dashboard'},
        controller: "DashboardController",

    })
```

home.html

```
<a href="#/dashboard">
```

Comment: Why would using another, third-party routing library be a solution? It is an alternative, but I do not think it answers the question.